# Получить записи с одинаковым f_key

Tags: sql

Есть некая таблица `tbl`:

```
id | f_key | alive
-------------------
   |       |
```

Есть еще поля, но они не имеют значения.

Я хочу узнать, есть ли у меня более одной "живой" на данный момент записи(alive = true), относящейся к одному 'f_key'.

На что способен я сам:
Я могу написать простой запрос

```
select * from tbl where alive = true order by f_key;
```

и сам глазами просмотреть: если в двух и более строках подряд есть одинаковый `f_key`, значит это то, что я ищу.

Но хотелось бы эту работу как-то автоматизировать. Понимаю что вопрос очень простой, и надо просто куда-то в условие вкорячить агрегатную функцию `count()`, значение которой болье единицы, но я запутался куда.

Comment: Вы бы указали DBMS и версию, для многих найдётся более изящное решение...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я вас верно понял, то вот такой запрос вернет количество:

```
select count(*) from tbl where alive = true group by f_key;
```

Если хотите знать какие именно ключи дублируются можно добавить `f_key` в вывод:

```
select count(*),f_key from tbl where alive = true group by f_key;
```

Если нужны именно целиком записи то вот такой запрос:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  tbl t1
where (
        Select 
          count(f_key) 
        from tbl t2 
        where 
          (alive = true) and // Эта строка если дубли нужны только среди "живых"
          t2.f_key=t1.f_key
      )>1
  and (alive = true)
```

Comment: Мне нужно не количество таких записей получить, а сами записи

Comment: Тогда минуту =)

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется это то, что нужно, сейчас проверю. Кажется второй `alive = true` уже не нужен

Comment: @Oleg без второго будет выводить все записи где более 2х живых f_key, т.е. выберет все записи есть как минимум 2 живых f_key и все мертвые для этих же f_key

Comment: Много раз пришлось перечитать последнее предложение, но в конце концов все таки дошло =)

Comment: @Oleg, мне бывает тяжеловато выразить простую мысль словами а не кодом\примером =)

Comment: Да тут скорее во мне проблема. Из-за посредственных знаний `sql` я не увидел сразу эту проблему, что увижу мертвые записи тоже

Answer (score 1):

Получить все записи:

```
with cte as ( select id, f_key, alive, sum(alive='alive') over (partition by f_key) cnt 
              from tbl )
select id, f_key, alive 
from cte 
where cnt > 1;
```

Получить только живые записи:

```
with cte as ( select id, f_key, alive, count(*) over (partition by f_key) cnt 
              from tbl 
              where alive='alive' )
select id, f_key, alive 
from cte 
where cnt > 1;
```

Диалект: MySQL 8+.